# python and csv how to pass if variable is empty?

Tags: python, selenium, csv, xls

```
    with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig',) as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([driver.current_url])
        all_data = [item_1.text, item_2.text, item_3.text, item_4.text,
                    item_5.text,item_6.text, item_7.text, item_8.text,
                    item_9.text, item_10.text,]
        filtered_strings = [string for string in all_data if string != ""]
        writer.writerow(filtered_strings)
```

error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'item_31' referenced before assignment

I use selenium to find elements than assigning each element to variable but some times the scripts doesn't get the data and I get error. how can i ignore if there is no data even if i already assigned it to variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Try and catch block to catch the exception.

```
try:
  your code
except:
  print("An exception catched")
```

To learn about try catch block you may refer to below link
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp